# Scholarly retorts to "Quining Qualia"?

Tags: consciousness, qualia, dennett

I've been reading and rereading Daniel Dennett's dismissal of qualia, and I have been wanting to see what some of the experts in the field think of his portrayal.

For example, has Nagel, Hoffman, or Chalmers responded specifically to these claims?

I feel like it would help me understand some of the bits with some completeness.

Comment: Phil papers lists citations of published articles that make it to their system, you can see papers that cite Dennett's paper [here](https://philpapers.org/rec/DENQQ) and [here](https://philpapers.org/rec/DENQQ-3) (scroll down to "citations of this work"). Google scholar can also do the same thing.